# error after compilation

Tags: c

```
error: expected ‘)’ before ‘[’ token 
  error  line is - void display(ptr[i]);
```

this is the error which i get after compilation, what does it mean, i have written a simple program in C

Comment: check it as ptr=ptr[i]; void display(ptr); and inform is there same error?

Comment: Why did you remove the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Issues :

- `void display(ptr[i]);`. You shouldn't include return type while calling the function. Return type should be collected and it is up to the caller to collect it. So, change `void display(ptr[i]);` to `display(ptr[i]);`
- main should always return something.

Answer (score 1):

I can only imagine you are missing a ')' on the line above that line. But more source code would help in identifying the problem.

Comment: Even having said that the snippet can see looks particularly dodgy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more context, but it looks like you are making a forward declaration.  If so, you need to provide a formal argument type.  Right now it looks like you are supplying an "actual" argument.

Also, be sure you have a semicolon finishing the prior line.  The lack of which can give some very strange error messages.

Answer (score 0):

`void display(ptr[i])` seems to be a function declaration, but `i` is no constant and `ptr` is no type? What is `void` for?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

When calling `display`, you should just do it like this:

```
display(ptr[i]);
```

If you insist on clarifying that its type is `void`, you can use this:

```
(void)display(ptr[i]);
```

You're also missing this at the top of your file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

You will need that for the `scanf` function.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
void display(ptr[i]);
```

to

```
display(ptr[i]);
```

When calling a function you don't need to specify the return type.

Also there is a typo in:

```
for(i-0;i<2;i++)
```

I guess you meant `i=0`